# Derivative of Tutte polynomial at -1

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings, tutte-polynomial

Let Tutte polynomial on graph with edge-set $E$ be defined as follows

$$f(q,v)=\sum_{A\subseteq E} q^{\kappa(A)} v^{|A|}$$

Here the sum is over all subgraphs $A$, $\kappa(A)$ is the number of connected components in $A$, $|A|$ is number of edges in $A$.

Let
$$g(q,v)=\frac{\partial}{\partial v} \log f(q,v)$$
$$h(q,v)=\frac{\partial}{\partial v} f(q,v)$$

Is anything known about $g(q,-1)$ or $h(q,-1)$?

(**Edit Oct 26 2010:** actually it's the [multivariate Tutte polynomial](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0503607) restricted to all $v$'s being equal, relation to regular Tutte polynomial in Jeremy Martin's answer)

**Update Oct 24 2010**

$f(q,-1)$ is the number of proper $q$ colorings, $h(q,-1)$ is ???, $g(q,-1)$ is their ratio. Below are tables of values of $h(q,-1)$ for paths, cycles, complete graphs. Columns give graph size, $n=3..6$, rows give $q=2..8$

[image] [<sup>(source)</sup>](http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/tutte-derivative.png)

Mathematica [code](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=9rwkCjGy) to generate this:

```
computeH[graphName_, q_] := (
   g = Normal[GraphData[graphName, "AdjacencyMatrix"]];
   edges = Select[Position[g, 1], #[[1]] < #[[2]] &];
   kr[x_, edge_] := Boole[x[[First[edge]]] == x[[Last[edge]]]];
   term[x_] := Times @@ (1 + v kr[x, #] & /@ edges);
   xs = Tuples[Range[q], Length[g]];
   f = Total[term /@ xs];
   D[f, v] /. v -> -1
   );
TableForm[
   Table[computeH[{#, n}, q], {q, 2, 8}, {n, 3, 6}]] & /@ {"Path", 
  "Cycle", "Complete"}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This polynomial isn't the usual Tutte polynomial, but it's equivalent.  Provided that $G$ is connected (which is probably the case you're interested in, and I'll assume), it looks like $f_G(q,v)=qv^{n-1}T_G(q/v+1,v+1)$, where $n$ is the number of vertices of $G$.

One thing that comes to mind is the Crapo beta invariant, which is $(-1)^n\chi_G'(1)$, where $\chi_G(k)=(-1)^{n-1}kT_G(1-k,0)$ is the chromatic polynomial.  (E.g., see exercise 22 of lecture 4 of Stanley's notes on hyperplane arrangements: http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/arrangements/arr.html.)  Your polynomials, especially $g$, might be related to this, but I haven't thought about the details.

Comment: The polynomial as given is actually just the partition function of the q-state Potts model; this is known to be equivalent to the Tutte Polynomial, but often it is useful to work with it in the given form.

Answer (score 1):

But if anyone is interested in formal derivatives of the original Tutte polynomial (for Matroids), there is a nice expression of its derivatives in terms of activities (which of course is how Tutte defined his polynomial originally) in this paper of Las Vergnas: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.5247.pdf.